# using checkboxes with userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have an user form designed with three listboxes. 
The 3 listboxes are populated by the location from three different sheets.

By selecting the listbox, the user can filter the data in the sheet "Data".

if the user is selecting the "BBE Bebra" from the Listbox1. then he could find the filtered result of Bebra in the sheet.

Similary, if the user is selecting from the Listbox2, the same procedure is followed and if the user is selecting from listbox3, the same procedure is followed.

The user can also, select all the three checkbox and looks for the filtered result in the sheet.

I have a issues with the working code.

1. If I am selecting the checkboxes and click "Filter" then I always see the filtered result. The next time I click on the Filter Button I would like to see the whole data sheet with filters clear and checkboxes cleared.

Can someone tell how I can do it ?

[image: Eevrytime, I could see the previous checked boxes in the userform.]
[image: Instead I would like to have the clear checkbox. (This means, when I click the button in my sheet which displays the userform should clear the filter result.]

Below is the code, I am using in the filter button

```
Sub DoFilter()
Dim strCriteria() As String
Dim strCriteria2() As String
Dim strcriteria3() As String
Dim arrIdx As Integer
Dim arrIdx2 As Integer
Dim arrIdx3 As Integer
Dim xRow As Integer
Dim arrCounter As Integer
Dim lo As ListObject
arrIdx = 0
arrIdx2 = 0
arrIdx3 = 0
For xRow = 2 To Last(1, List.Cells)
    If List.Cells(xRow, 2) = True Then
        ReDim Preserve strCriteria(0 To arrIdx)
        strCriteria(arrIdx) = List.Cells(xRow, 3)
        arrIdx = arrIdx + 1
    End If
Next xRow
For xRow = 2 To Last(1, List.Cells)
    If List_Man.Cells(xRow, 2) = True Then
        ReDim Preserve strCriteria2(0 To arrIdx2)
        strCriteria2(arrIdx2) = List_Man.Cells(xRow, 3)
        arrIdx2 = arrIdx2 + 1
    End If
Next xRow

For xRow = 2 To Last(1, List.Cells)
If List_S.Cells(xRow, 2) = True Then
ReDim Preserve strcriteria3(0 To arrIdx3)
strcriteria3(arrIdx3) = List_S.Cells(xRow, 3)
arrIdx3 = arrIdx3 + 1
End If
Next xRow

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set lo = Ws.ListObjects("Table7")
If arrIdx = 0 And arrIdx2 = 0 And arrIdx3 = 0 Then
    'Ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
Else
    With Ws
    With lo

      '.AutoFilterMode = True

       ' .UsedRange.AutoFilter
        If arrIdx <> 0 Then
           .Range.AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:=Array(strCriteria), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
        If arrIdx2 <> 0 Then
           .Range.AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:=Array(strCriteria2), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
        If arrIdx3 <> 0 Then
       .Range.AutoFilter field:=15, Criteria1:=Array(strcriteria3), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If

        If .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count = 1 Then
            MsgBox " Your filter has no result"
        End If
    End With
    End With

Dim i As Long
On Error Resume Next
     With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dev").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Lo.")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Next
       For arrCounter = LBound(strCriteria) To UBound(strCriteria)
            .PivotItems(strCriteria(arrCounter)).Visible = True
        Next arrCounter
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

I call the function do filter in my button "Filter". 
with the button "exit" I always have the 
following code

```
Private Sub CBExit_Click()
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

Sheets("Dev").Select
Sheets("Dev").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Development Loc.").ClearAllFilters
Unload Me
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep track of your current state using some sort of flag.  I would do something like the following:

```
Private Sub Filter_Click()
   If Filter.Caption = "Filter" Then
      DoFilter
      Filter.Caption = "Unfilter"
   Else
      'do logic to clear
      Filter.Caption = "Filter"
   End If
End Sub
```

This has the added benefit of telling the user what the next click of the button will do.

Comment: I will try and get back to you in case of doubt

Comment: This idea is cool :) But I would like to ask you, If it is possible , to uncheck the checkboxes automatically when I do unfilter ?

Comment: for unfiltering I am using the logic  If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If